# MYSQL Table design help

Tags: mysql

I have  a table called teams (id, name, ...)   I have a table called divisions (id, name, ......)   I want the diviosn to hold the teams.id  for each team in a divsion  and Teams can be in more than one divsion.  How do I set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your tables looked like this

```
teams
-teamId
-teamName

divisions
-divisionId
-divisionName
```

I think what you are looking for is a many-to-many link table

```
membership
-divisionId
-teamId
```

This would allow you to find all the teams in a division with

```
select teamId
from team t
join membership m
  on m.teamId = t.teamId
where m.divisionId = 'theIdYouWant'
```

It would also allow as many teams as you want to belong to a division and as many divisions as you want to contain the same teams. It's a many to many relationship table.

Comment: So   membership -divisionId -teamId     I would only have two fields both being a primary key?  or do I need an additional key that is auto incremented?

Comment: No primary key needed on a link table.

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard approach for a many-to-many relationship: Make a separate table teams_divisons (or divisions_teams) that contains two columns team_id and division_id.

Answer (score 0):

You create what's called a relationship table. It's an intermediary table between the Teams tables and the Divisions table. Then we say that there is a many-to-many relationship between the Teams table (tbl_teams) and Divisions table (tbl_divisions). You can have many teams in one division, one team in many divisions, or many teams in many divisions.

tbl_teams_divisions_rel

- ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
- Team_ID INT NOT NULL
- Division_ID INT NOT NULL

Then you establish a relationship between tbl_teams_divisions_rel.Team_ID and tbl_team.ID, and then between tbl_teams_divisions_rel.Division_ID and tbl_divisions.ID

If you ask the question, how to list all teams in a particular division with ID 13, you would do the following:

```
SELECT tbl_teams.*
FROM
    tbl_teams
    INNER JOIN tbl_teams_divisions_rel ON tbl_teams_divisions_rel.Team_ID = tbl_teams.ID
WHERE tbl_teams_divisions_rel.Division_ID = 13
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks I will try it out.  Is the ID field as primary necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You could add two columns - `division_names` to teams which will contain the names of teams that are in each division, and `team_names` to divisions which will contain the names of the divisions that team is a part of.

When you add a team or division, follow it by a `;`, then you can create an array of teams or divisions based on that field by using `$field = explode(";", $field);`, and then list the teams or divisions using `foreach()`.

That's assuming you're using PHP. Let me know if I misunderstood you.

Comment: That is how I originally did it just seems a little cumbersome.  Yes I am using PHP MYSQL and Joomla.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think of adding a relationship table. See...any of the other answers for details. :p

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a many-to-many junction table to join division and team tables.

```
CREATE TABLE division (division_id INT NOT NULL,
                     PRIMARY KEY (division_id)
);

CREATE TABLE team (team_id INT NOT NULL,
                     PRIMARY KEY (team_id)
);

CREATE TABLE division_team (division_team_id INT, 
                    PRIMARY KEY (division_team_id)
                    division_id INT, 
                    team_id INT,
                    FOREIGN KEY (division_id) REFERENCES division(division_id),
                    FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES team(team_id),
);
```

Comment: is the division_team_id really necessary?  Could you just make the div_id and team_id both be primary keys?

Comment: it depends... you can make a composite primary key using division_id and team_id too, if you want. But then if division_team table becomes a parent to some other table, it is better to have division_team_id primary key so that the children tables don't need to inherit the composite IDs as foreign keys.